# Twig string comparison always evaluates to true

Tags: string, symfony, symfony1, twig

I am having a hard time comparing strings in a Twig template. The following example always evaluates to true, even though the `res.website` clearly contains the string `none` which should make the if statement evaluate to false.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to get it evaluate to true only when the string is **not** equal to `none`?

Many thanks in advance!

```
   {{res.website}}//output: none
```

Twig (evaluates to true!)

```
{% if "{{res.website}}" != "none" %}
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/foo/images/web-icon.png') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Note: when I remove the quotes from around the `if "{{ ... }}"` I get the following error:

`A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclosing your variable with double quotes will definitely not give the expected result. It will simply treat `{{res.website}}` as a string and compare it with `none`.

Simply write:

```
{% if res.website != "none" %}
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/foo/images/web-icon.png') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

If you still have an error, make sure `res` is a valid variable in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `{% %}` no need to enclose the variable `{{ }}`

use

```
{% if res.website != "none" %}
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/foo/images/web-icon.png') }}" />
{% endif %}
```